# Vue, content from routerview hidden

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to make it so my navigation pane will appear over the content of the page, instead, it just appends it to the bottom of the page where the end of the navigation drawer would be.  I have tried a few different variants to get data to show using navigation drawers as well as list item groups inside the navigation drawer.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>

    <v-content>
    <SideBar class="hidden-lg-and-up" v-bind:navButtons="navButtons"></SideBar>
    <TopBar class="hidden-md-and-down" v-bind:navButtons="navButtons"></TopBar>

      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-content>

  </v-app>

</template>

<script>
import TopBar from './components/Navigation/TopBar'
import SideBar from './components/Navigation/SideBar'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      navButtons: [
        { title: "Home", icon: "home", route: "/" },
        { title: "Search", icon: "search", route: "/search" },
        { title: "About Us", icon: "help", route: "/about" }
      ]
    }
  },
  components: {
    TopBar,
    SideBar
  }

};
</script>
```

SideBar.vue

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-app-bar app color="#524366" dark>
            <v-app-bar-nav-icon class="align-right" @click="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
        </v-app-bar>
        <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" :color="color" absolute dark>
            <v-list dense nav class="py-0">
                <v-list-item two-line>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title>Site Navigation</v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>

                <v-divider></v-divider>

                <v-list-item v-for="item in this.navButtons" :key="item.title" :to="item.route" link>
                    <v-list-item-icon>
                        <v-icon class="material-icons">{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-icon>

                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      drawer: true,

      color: '#4c5073',
      colors: [
        'primary',
        'blue',
        'success',
        'red',
        'teal',
      ],
      right: false,
      permanent: true,
      expandOnHover: false,
      background: false,
    }
  },
    props: {
        navButtons: {
            type: Array
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Any clue as to why this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution to implement what I wanted.

Toolbar.vue

```
<template>
    <nav>
        <v-app-bar color="#524366" app dark>
            <div class="d-flex align-center">
                <v-img
                    alt="Sultana Logo"
                    class="shrink mr-2 hidden-md-and-down"
                    contain
                    src="@/assets/logo.png"
                    transition="scale-transition"
                    width="80"
                />
            </div>
            <v-spacer class="hidden-md-and-down"></v-spacer>
            <v-app-bar-nav-icon class="hidden-lg-and-up" right @click="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
            <v-btn right class="hidden-md-and-down" v-for="(item, index) in this.navButtons" :key="index" :to="item.route" text>
                {{ item.title }}
                <v-icon :key="index" class="material-icons ml-2">{{ item.iconName }}</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </v-app-bar>

        <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" :color="color" absolute dark>
            <v-list shaped dense nav class="py-0">
                <v-list-item two-line>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title>Site Navigation</v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>

                <v-divider></v-divider>

                <v-list-item v-for="item in this.navButtons" :key="item.title" :to="item.route" link>
                    <v-list-item-icon>
                        <v-icon class="material-icons">{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>

    </nav>

</template>


<script>

export default {
    name: 'TopBar',

    data() {
        return {
            drawer: false,
            color: '#4c5073',
        }
    },

    props: {
        navButtons: {
            type: Array
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>

    <v-content>
      <Toolbar v-bind:navButtons="navButtons"></Toolbar>
            <router-view></router-view>

    <!-- <SideBar class="hidden-lg-and-up" v-bind:navButtons="navButtons"></SideBar>
    <TopBar class="hidden-md-and-down" v-bind:navButtons="navButtons"></TopBar> -->

    </v-content>

  </v-app>

</template>

<script>
// import TopBar from './components/Navigation/TopBar'
// import SideBar from './components/Navigation/SideBar'
import Toolbar from '@/components/Navigation/Toolbar'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      navButtons: [
        { title: "Home", icon: "home", route: "/" },
        { title: "Search", icon: "search", route: "/search" },
        { title: "About Us", icon: "help", route: "/about" }
      ]
    }
  },
  components: {
    // TopBar,
    // SideBar
    Toolbar
  }

};
</script>
```